# Where do I mark a lambda expression async?

Tags: c#, lambda, resharper, windows-store-apps, async-await

I've got this code:

```
private async void ContextMenuForGroupRightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    CheckBox ckbx = null;
    if (sender is CheckBox)
    {
        ckbx = sender as CheckBox;
    }
    if (null == ckbx)
    {
        return;
    }
    string groupName = ckbx.Content.ToString();

    var contextMenu = new PopupMenu();

    // Add a command to edit the current Group
    contextMenu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Edit this Group", (contextMenuCmd) =>
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(LocationGroupCreator), groupName);
    }));

    // Add a command to delete the current Group
    contextMenu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Delete this Group", (contextMenuCmd) =>
    {
        SQLiteUtils slu = new SQLiteUtils();
        slu.DeleteGroupAsync(groupName); // this line raises Resharper's hackles, but appending await raises err msg. Where should the "async" be?
    }));

    // Show the context menu at the position the image was right-clicked
    await contextMenu.ShowAsync(args.GetPosition(this));
}
```

...that Resharper's inspection complained about with, "*Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call*" (on the line with the comment).

And so, I prepended an "await" to it but, of course, I then need to add an "async" somewhere, too - but where?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#async-lambdas

Comment: @samsara: Nice, I wonder when they finally documented that somewhere outside the C# spec. IIRC, no documentation existed at the time this question was asked.

Answer (score 464, accepted):

To mark a lambda async, simply prepend `async` before its argument list:

```
// Add a command to delete the current Group
contextMenu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Delete this Group", async (contextMenuCmd) =>
{
    SQLiteUtils slu = new SQLiteUtils();
    await slu.DeleteGroupAsync(groupName);
}));
```

Comment: I get an error from Visual Studio that Async void methods are not supported.

Comment: @Kevin Burton: Yeah, async voids are usually only limited to event handlers. The API you're using is either not async or has an async version expecting an async Task lambda instead.

Comment: Can anyone help me out by giving some link to explanation how such async lambdas would execute?

Comment: @ed22: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks but I still don't understand how async lambda parameter that is not awaited executes...

Comment: @ed22: Async void methods are exclusively event handlers. Nothing is awaiting them, they just go off and do their own thing.

Comment: @ed22 An API is asking you to give it a parameter of type: method which returns a `Task`. Async lambda, like an async method, is a way for you to write such methods. If someone calls your async method or lambda, it will execute the code you wrote and the `Task` it returns will be set completed when the code is finished. Presumably, if someone asks you for such a method, they intend to call it and await.

Answer (score 61):

And for those of you using an anonymous expression:

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
   SQLLiteUtils slu = new SQLiteUtils();
   await slu.DeleteGroupAsync(groupname);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are inside a LINQ method syntax apply the async keyword right before the parameter:

```
 list.Select(async x =>
            {
                await SomeMethod(x);
                return true;
            });
```

Comment: What does the `return true;` represents?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias sorry for the poor explanation. The return true; represents what each value of the list should return, in my case the list was List<bool>, so from one list you are creating another list with Select() method. For the sake of simplicity I removed my logic. The important part here is that I needed to call an awaitable method inside a lambda expression and that is done by putting the async keyword.

Comment: Drilon if the `list` is a `List<bool>`, then the `x` is a `bool`. This is clear. The `return true;` is not clear. Why would you return a constant value instead of the result of the `await SomeMethod(x)`, or at least the `x` itself? And where is this return value used? Your example does not assign the result of the `list.Select` to anything. Sorry, but for the time being I have to downvote the answer. You could try to improve it by editing it if you want.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry for what you are...
The return depends on the awaitable method. Example. if SomeMethod returns not null , return true, else return false, and that will do a mapping of each vaule. But I did not want to provide all the code since it is irrelevant for the async keyword problem.