# Is there a way to create a property that return Task<Delegate>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I want to be able to have a getter property that will take an instance of `IService` and return a delegate that would be called async.

For instance:

```
public class DelAccessor
{
    public Func<IService, Task<Delegate>> Getter { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to invoke it like this `await a.Getter(service);`

I am struggling with the correct syntax

```
new DelAccessor()
{
    Getter = service => (Func<string, Task<object>>)((t) =>
            {
                var v = new object();

                // perform async call
                return v;
            });
```

I get a compiler error

> Cannot implicitly convert type `Func<string, Task<object>>` to `Task<Delegate>`

What is the correct way to define the getter that can be called async?

Comment: Property-getters shouldn't have side-effects... so why do you want to do this?

Comment: Would `await a.Getter(service);` return `v`, or would `await a.Getter(service).Invoke("some string");` return `v`?

Comment: @Dai what do you mean by "shouldn't have side-effects"? @Sweeper `await a.Getter(service);`

Comment: It looks like you want `Getter = async service => { ... }`

Comment: Well if `await a.Getter(service)` returns `v`, what would be the argument `t`?

Comment: "getter that can be called async" - there is no such thing in C# as asynchronous properties... and it does not look like you are looking for one either. It is possible you are looking for a property that returns a factory method (based on `Func<IService, Task<Delegate>>` return signature the question shows) but you will not be able to call that getter async anyway (resulting Func can be used to start a task to await... even on the same line but to me it is a very different operation)

Answer (score 1):

To [mark lambda async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015319/where-do-i-mark-a-lambda-expression-async) you need to add `async` before arguments:

```
System.Delegate v = (async (string a) => { await Task.Delay(1); return 1;});
```

As result to make code the question to compile:

```
var delAccessor = new DelAccessor()
{
    Getter = async service =>
    {
        Delegate x = (Func<string, Task<object>>)(async (t) =>
            {
                var v = new object();

                await Task.Delay(1);
                return v;
            });
        await Task.Delay(2);
        return x;
    }
};
```

Note that `await a.Getter(service);` call will give you an untyped delegate that you still need to call with a string parameter and `await` result to obtain `v` at the end.

Sample code to call that end-to-end (if you are ok with `dynamic`):

```
dynamic d = await delAccessor .Getter(service);
var r = await d("test");
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would likely work. You have a `delegate` for the `Task<string>` called `ReadFileDelegate` (renamed it for clarity in the example) and a read-only property for the `delegate` of type `ReadFileDelegate`.

```cs
public class DelAccessor
{
    public delegate Task<string> ReadFileDelegate(string name);

    public ReadFileDelegate ReadFile => ReadFileText;

    private async Task<string> ReadFileText(string name)
    {
        var str = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(name);
        return str;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var d = new DelAccessor();
var text = d.ReadFile(@"C:\test.txt");
```

If you wanted to you could move the function and then set the `ReadFile` property in another class if you change it to:

```cs
// you could also use set (instead of init) depending on your needs
public ReadFileDelegate ReadFile { get; init; }
```

The actual `ReadFileText` function could then be moved to wherever.